# Nested routes for controllers in Nest.js

Tags: routes, controller, nest

I'm using Nest.js for creating a REST-api and also incorporating Nest.js microservices.

I'm having a routing structure that looks like this:

```
@Controller('users/:userId/cars/:itemId')
@Controller('users/:userId/houses/:itemId')
@Controller('users/:userId/pets/:itemId')
```

I would like to accomplish having a single controller only taking care of operations regarding **'users/:userId'** before moving on the next separate controller responsible for **'/cars/:itemId'** and so on. That way I can have all my logic handling and responding with a 404 response if no user is found before entering my concurrent **'/cars/:itemId'**-endpoints.

I would like my children controllers routes to look like this (although passing through the route **'users/userId'** firstly) and still being able to access the **'userId'**-path parameter:

```
@Controller('cars/:itemId')
@Controller('houses/:itemId')
@Controller('pets/:itemId')
```

As I'm using microservices all my controllers are hosted in separate applications and separate modules:

1. Users
2. Cars
3. Houses
4. Pets

I have tried using the [Router module](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/router-module) with children but to no avail (children routes won't work).

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a userService with a method that handles that logic. That service will take the userId as an argument

You can use that service method with the route **users/:userId**.

Then for the other part of the question instead of calling @Controller('users/:userId/houses/:itemId') I would call **@Controller('houses/:userId/:itemId')**. Inside that route, you first need to call the usersService and access the method created before, after that you can call the houseService if needed or throw a 404 if there is no user.